# Dom object width has a minimum of 320

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to know the orientation of the dom screen at any moment, so also when resizing etc. I am using a stream/ RxJS framework which gives me a stream of events everytime at resizing and it returns an object. I try to find the height and width properties and get quite close using these:

```
fromEvented('resize', myMap)
  .forEach(x => console.log(x.target._canvas.clientHeight, x.target._canvas.clientWidth, x.target._canvas.clientHeight > x.target._canvas.clientWidth))
```

So when True it is Portrait, otherwise Lanscape.

But somehow the width has a minimum of 320. So I keep getting 320 even when resizing to a smaller actual width. Which attributes should I use? Or can I also somehow use CSS values (I am a kn00b...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x I get back is a Mapbox map object. I solved it by ignoring it and simply using html5 events. As I use most.js for streams I used resize from @most/dom-event and then the `event.currentTarget.innerWidth`; Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use document.documentElement.clientWidth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth
in Jquery for example

```
$(window).resize(function(){ console.log(document.documentElement.clientWidth);})
```

Comment: That would not give a reactive stream I think...?!